# SQL Server: Function that returns value if first or last row in result set?

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering if there is a function in SQL Server that can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    itemId, 
    itemTitle, 
    isFirstRow(itemId) AS isFirst, 
    isLastRow(itemId) AS isLast
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY itemId
```

Example desired results:

```
itemId  itemTitle     isFirst  isLast
------  ------------  -------  ------
     1  An item       TRUE     FALSE
     2  The world     FALSE    FALSE
     3  Code          FALSE    FALSE
     4  Something     FALSE    TRUE
```

The thing is I want the first and last row values to be representative of a specific ordering of the table, NOT necessarily the order in which the results are returned. In this case, the itemId value is the key.

```
SELECT 
    itemId, 
    itemTitle, 
    isFirstRow(itemId ascending) as isFirst, 
    isLastRow(itemId ascending) as isLast 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY itemTitle

itemId  itemTitle     isFirst  isLast
------  ------------  -------  ------
     1  An item       TRUE     FALSE
     3  Code          FALSE    FALSE
     4  Something     FALSE    TRUE
     2  The world     FALSE    FALSE
```

Or another example:

```
SELECT 
    itemId, 
    itemTitle, 
    isFirstRow(itemTitle descending) AS isFirst,
    isLastRow(itemTitle descending) AS isLast
FROM myTable 
WHERE itemId > 1
ORDER BY itemId

itemId  itemTitle     isFirst  isLast
------  ------------  -------  -----------
     2  The world     TRUE     FALSE
     3  Code          FALSE    FALSE
     4  Something     FALSE    FALSE
```

The use case would be returning a result set, or even a single record from that result set, to a front end application, but allowing the front application to know whether it's the first or last record in a specific ordering without having to make a separate query and do a "count of records" or "max/min" strategy (which wouldn't even work on a text field).

I'm imagining a subquery might be able to do this but am not sure how the syntax would look.

Comment: In your 3rd example was are no rows isLast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `CASE` and `ROW_NUMBER`

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
  itemid INT,
  itemtitle VARCHAR(10),
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1, 'An item')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (3, 'Code')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (4, 'Something')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2, 'The world')


SELECT 
  itemid,
  itemtitle,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY itemid ASC) = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS isFirst,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY itemid DESC) = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS isLast
FROM #temp
ORDER BY itemtitle
```

Comment: This site never fails me! Awesome! THANK YOU!